# View pager not loading when set dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet

I have opened a bottom sheet with viewpager on an activity which has details along with comment and activity stream. However the bottom sheet is opened when clicked on a list item on a fragment in the activity. The comment and activity streams are called separately when list item is clicked through a network call passing id.

Everything goes well when i pass a static id and set the bottom sheet view as soon as the fragment is populated with data.

The challenge has been while trying to pass id dynamically. I am trying to setup the viewpager and tab layout when the listitem is clicked. Here's how..

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager_story);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new ActivityCommentAdapter(getFragmentManager(),storyId);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

However this never loads the view pager in the UI thus no list is shown.
Apart from the No-View, one strange thing i noticed while debugging is, this certainly goes to the network and gets the data, but the adapter to set list does not gets called properly. Only the constructor is called not the onBindViewHolder()...

I have done days of search, please help...

```
public class ActivityCommentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private  String storyId;
public ActivityCommentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String storyId) {
    super(fm);
    this.storyId=storyId;

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position, storyId);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Comments";
        case 1:
            return "Activity";
    }
    return null;
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    List<CommentListModal.Datum> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rvList;
    CommentsAdapter mAdapter;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    String token;
    Retrofit retrofit;
    ListApis requestApi;
    String storyId;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    public void getCommentsForStory(String storyId) {

        Call<CommentListModal> call = requestApi.getCommentsForStory(token, "525", "story", storyId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CommentListModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CommentListModal> call, Response<CommentListModal> response) {

                if (response.body().getStatus() == 100) {
                    mAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(response.body().getData(), "1", "1");
                    rvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else if (response.body().getStatus() == 101) {
                    System.out.println("Error--->" + response.body().getError());
                    //Snackbar.make(fabButton, response.body().getError().get(0), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (response.body().getStatus() == 102) {
                    System.out.println("Error--->" + response.body().getError());
                    //Snackbar.make(fabButton, response.body().getError().get(0), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CommentListModal> call, Throwable t) {

                System.out.println("Failure Response---->" + call);
            }
        });

    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, String storyId) {
        System.out.println("Place holder instance: " + storyId);
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        args.putString("sid", storyId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment, container, false);
        Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.BASE_URL))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        requestApi = retrofit.create(ListApis.class);

        token = getString(R.string.token);

        mPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_filename),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rvList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvList.setAdapter(null);

        getCommentsForStory(storyId);
        /*mAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(comments, "1", "1");
        rvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);*/
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: upload your ActivityCommentAdapter code, i guess you are not creating the correct object of your fragment, and also try to upload the code of fragment, whose object you are creating in getItem() inside the pager adapter(ActivityCommentAdapter).

Comment: @HAXM: i have added the said code... kindly check...

Comment: use this new ActivityCommentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),storyId);    Certain things i'm unable to understand in your code however i prefer you to use:   @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
        args.putString("sid", storyId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}